# showing huge number of images on device if you have low device memory in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I have 200 images of 5MB but my device memory has 500MB available for usage. How can you show the images in an `UITableView`?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You can use [this](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) library, when call `didReceiveMemoryWarning` it automatically clear cache, and memory usage are down

Comment: Just create the image on the fly no need to save images in memory

Comment: If you cache the Image you will get the memory warning. Try to get them from the disk when the cell is called. Or reduce your images for the tableView (5Mb is very high, and tableview cell are small, you could also use thumbnails to avoid high memory usage)

Comment: DONOT store `UIImage` directly in your dataSource array or you will get crash, you have to store them in app's document storage, and store only the name of the image in your array, when cell reuse then get the image out  in there

Answer (score -1):

The amount of images shouldn't matter. UITableViewCell gets dequeued, which in short means you're recycling your cells and preserving memory. Creating a tableView with images shouldn't be a problem, just make sure you create dequeueable cells like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    //configure your cell

    return cell
}
```

Comment: It's not related to cell reusable, the OP probably trying to store the UIImage in the array which cause the crash

Comment: Based on OP's question it's hard to assume what he probably wants. His question is how he can show the images in the tableView, not how to save these images in an array (or database).